# Convert number to their log2

Tags: ruby, math, floating-accuracy

I need to convert number into their minimal log2 +1, but I have a problem, that in 32-bit Ruby, log2(8) = 2.9999999999999996

The input (`pos`) and output (`level`) should be:

```
1 -> 1
2-3 -> 2
4-7 -> 3
8-15 -> 4
16-31 -> 5
and so on..
```

My formula:

```
pos = 8 
level = ( Math.log(pos,2) + 1 ).to_i
# 3 (wrong) in 32-bit Ruby
# 4 (correct) in 64-bit Ruby
```

Is there more way to prevent this from happening or is there any other formula that convert `pos` to correct `level` as shown above?

Comment: and yes, it only happened for certain number: 8, 64, 4096, 8192, 16777216, 67108864, 281474976710656, 2251799813685248, etc '___') i don't know why

Comment: Floating point precision I'm afraid. Just the way the cookie crumbles. But it's nearly correct, no?

Comment: No '___') 1 difference between 3 to 4 makes my another algorithm become faulty XD

Comment: Well, it's that algorithm that's at fault. Floating points are difficult to work with.

Comment: What values do you have for `RUBY_VERSION` and `RUBY_PLATFORM`?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You seem to want the integer part of log **plus 1**. That is your particular problem. When asking a question here, extract the core/minimal part of the question. Ask for log, not log plus 1.

Comment: puts "#{RUBY_PLATFORM} #{RUBY_VERSION}"
i686-linux 2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pos = 8
level = 0
until pos < 2
  level += 1
  pos /= 2
end
level + 1 #=> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another interesting way to compute the floored logarithm for integers:

```
0.upto(Float::INFINITY).find{|e| x - base**e < base }
```

Comment: Although @sawa's answer should perform much better, because it does only one division for each potential exponent, whereas mine does an exponentiation for each one.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum representable value with [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) `binary32` is `(2−2**(−23)) × 2**127`, so the `base 2 log` of a number stored in binary 32 is less than decimal 128. Since the round-off error is a small fraction of one, we can round to the nearest integer and see if 2 to that integer power equals the given number.  If it does, return the integer power; else return `nil`, signifying that it is not a power of 2.

```
def log_2_if_integer(n)
  x = Math.log(n,2).round(0).to_i
  (2**x == n) ? x : nil
end

log_2_if_integer(4)   #=> 2
log_2_if_integer(512) #=> 9
log_2_if_integer(3)   #=> nil
```

In other words, because the log is less than 128, rounding error could not produce a value `x` such that `2**(x+m) == n` for any (positive or negative) integer `m != 0`.

Comment: I think OP wants an answer even if it's not a power of 2: `8-15 -> 4`.

Comment: @Teepeemm, I have two things to say about your comment: 1. Isn't it pretty obvious that you could return a float rather than `nil` if the value is not a power of 2? 2. Neither of the other two answers even checked to see if the number was a power of 2. I'm not faulting them, as I'm sure they thought such a check was trivial, as it is.

Comment: "the base 2 log of a number stored in binary 32 is not more than decimal 8".  This isn't right: the largest number that can be stored in IEEE 754 binary32 format is close to `2^128`, so its base-two log would be close to `128`.  I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the binary32 format to the question, either: doesn't Ruby use double-precision floats (binary64) under the hood?

Comment: @MarkDickinson, thanks for pointing that out. I certainly messed that up, but it doesn't affect the validity of the method. The OP was specific about 32-bit Ruby. Please see my  edit.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit Ruby: it'll be using the binary64 format either way.

Comment: I don't understand how Ruby could be using binary64 with a 32-bit processor. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, Intel processors have had an FPU with 80-bit registers for quite a while (for some history, see [Wikipedia's entry on x87](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X87)); a 32-bit OS will typically use those registers for single, double and extended precision floating-point computations, while a 64-bit OS is more likely to use the newer SSE2 instructions.  But there's no reason in principle a 32-bit processor couldn't do 64-bit computations.  See [here](http://superuser.com/a/790231) for a more complete explanation.